# Debugging iterative squareroot approximator

Tags: python, debugging

I'm currently doing an exercise that goes as follows:
"Debug the following code. Test it for numbers like {-4, 0, 0.5, 1, 3, 9, 34} and larger numbers as well."

```
def mySqrt(number, guess, step, tol):
    #We need to take out negative numbers...
    if (number<0):
        print('Error - we do not work with complex numbers here...')
        return float("NaN")
        
    #If we set guess to zero, we have to provide a number - we assume this is the initial call
    if (guess==0):
        if (number>1):        #If we have numbers larger than one, we can safely guess half as the sqrt
            guess=0.5*number
        else:
            guess=number*2    #If we have numbers smaller than one, we need to double our guess
        
    tmp = guess*guess         #Now compute the square of our guess
    if ((tmp-number)>tol):    #Check if the (guess^2 - number) is lower than our tolerance level
        return guess
    else:
        if (tmp>number):      #If our guess was too high, then iterate by calling ourselves again with a slightly lower guess
            return mySqrt(number, (1+step)*guess, step, tol)
        else:                 #Else, our guess was too small, we need to increase the guess for our next call
            return mySqrt(number, (1-step)*guess, step, tol)
            

testVal = 9
print('Squareroot of '+str(testVal)+' is ')
print(mySqrt(testVal,0,0.001, 0.001))
```

I've tried going through the code line by line but Im not getting anywhere, mostly because Im unsure what the code is actually supposed to output. Any advice is helpful.

Comment: "non successfully" does not tell us anything.

Comment: Have you looked at each line of code to check that it does what it is supposed to? For example with the line `if((tmp-number)>tol):` it has the comment "Check if the (guess^2 - number) is lower than our tolerance level", however the if statement is doing the opposite.

Comment: Similarly, the line after the comment "If our guess was too high, then iterate by calling ourselves again with a slightly lower guess", it looks like it's actually increasing the guess rather than decreasing it.

Comment: The code is supposed to output the square root of the input argument, isn't it ?

Comment: Side remark: I have never seen such a rotten square root algorithm !

Answer (score 0):

Im getting closer to the solution :D

```
def mySqrt(number, guess, step, tol):
    #We need to take out negative numbers...
    if (number<0):
        print('Error - we do not work with complex numbers here...')
        return float("NaN")
        
    #If we set guess to zero, we have to provide a number - we assume this is the initial call
    if (guess==0):
        if (number>1):        #If we have numbers larger than one, we can safely guess half as the sqrt
            guess=0.5*number
        else:
            guess=number*2    #If we have numbers smaller than one, we need to double our guess
        
    tmp = guess*guess         #Now compute the square of our guess
    if ((tmp-number)<tol):    #Check if the (guess^2 - number) is lower than our tolerance level
        return guess
    else:
        if (tmp>number):      #If our guess was too high, then iterate by calling ourselves again with a slightly lower guess
            return mySqrt(number, (1-step)*guess, step, tol)
        else:                 #Else, our guess was too small, we need to increase the guess for our next call
            return mySqrt(number, (1+step)*guess, step, tol)
```

Thank you to the responders!

Comment: This code does not generate square roots (estimates)

Answer (score 0):

A recursive approach is unnecessary. You just need a simple loop. Something like this:

```
def mySqrt(a, epsilon=0.0001):
    if a > 0:
        x = a / 2
        while True:
            y = (x + a / x) / 2
            if abs(y - x) <= epsilon:
                return y
            x = y
    return float('nan')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the exercise is not to create the method, just debug already made code :( But thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's clarify what is what:

1. tol - accurancy. If the difference between result and expected result becomes less than accurancy, it means we found the solution. So, we shound change

`(tmp-number)>tol`
to
`(tmp-number)<tol`

2. Algorithm: we try to guess what number is the square root of given. Then we are raising it to the second degree and compairing with the given number. If the result less then needed, we should add step to guess. Else - take away. So, we should change:

   ````
   if (tmp>number):
       return mySqrt(number, (1+step)*guess, step, tol)
   else:
       return mySqrt(number, (1-step)*guess, step, tol)```
   ````

to

```
if (tmp>number):
    return mySqrt(number, (1-step)*guess, step, tol)
else:
    return mySqrt(number, (1+step)*guess, step, tol)
```